# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, retrofit, realm

Есть такой интерфейс:

**BackendlessAPI.java**

```
    String BASE_URL = "https://api.backendless.com/" + APP_ID + "/" + API_KEY +"/";
    String IMAGES_FOLDER = "shops_images";
    String IMAGES_URL = BASE_URL + "files/" + IMAGES_FOLDER + "/";

    @GET("data/Shop")
    Observable<Shop> listShops();
```

Делаю REST запрос вот так:

**DataManager.java**

```
@Override
public Observable<Shop> loadShopsFromWeb() {
    Log.d(DEFAULT_TAG, "Try to load from web");
    final IDatabaseHelper databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance();
    BackendlessAPI backendlessAPI = backendlessRetrofit.create(BackendlessAPI.class);
    Observable<Shop> shopsList = backendlessAPI
            .listShops()
            .timeout(LOAD_SHOPS_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(shop -> {
                databaseHelper.cacheShop(shop);
                return shop;
            });

    return shopsList;
}
```

Ожидается примерно такой JSON в ответ на запрос:

```
[
    {
        "created": 1500137157543,
        "imageUrl": "pekarnya.png",
        "name": "Пекарня на Патриотов",
        "___class": "Shop",
        "coordinates": [
            {
                "lng": 60.673511,
                "city": "Yekaterinburg",
                "street": "Патриотов 70",
                "created": 1500111228678,
                "city_ru": "Екатеринбург",
                "___class": "ShopGeoPoint",
                "lat": 56.782548,
                "objectId": "75F88D38-F831-1828-FF44-7CA466868F00"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Хотите качественную и вкусную выпечку? Заказывай наисвежайшие булочки в \"Пекарне на Патриотов\"",
        "type": "Пекарня",
        "objectId": "C97EDFBC-04BB-D59A-FFE0-A45138B1ED00"
    }
]
```

А вот мои POJO

**Shop.java**

```
public class Shop extends RealmObject {

    public Shop() {
    }

    public Shop(RealmList<ShopGeoPoint> coordinates, String name, String objectId, String imageUrl,
                String description, String type) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
        this.name = name;
        this.objectId = objectId;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.description = description;
        this.type = type;
    }


    public RealmList<ShopGeoPoint> getCoordinates() {
        return  coordinates;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(RealmList<ShopGeoPoint> coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(String objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


    private RealmList<ShopGeoPoint> coordinates;
    @Required
    private String name;
    @Required
    @PrimaryKey
    private String objectId;
    private String description;
    @Required
    private String imageUrl;
    private String type;



}
```

**ShopGeoPoint.java**

```
public class ShopGeoPoint extends RealmObject {


    public ShopGeoPoint(double lat, double lng, String street, String objectId) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.street = street;
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }


    public ShopGeoPoint() {
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public String getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(String objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    private double lat;
    private double lng;
    @Required
    private String street;
    @PrimaryKey
    private String objectId;


}
```

POJO кешируются вот так:

**DatabaseManager.java**

```
@Override
    public void cacheShop(final Shop shop) throws NullPointerException {
        if(realm == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("Realm didn't init. Use getInstance() to get DatabaseHelper");
        }
        Log.d(DEFAULT_TAG, "Shop is cached");
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                bgRealm.copyToRealm(shop);
            }
        });
    }
```

Почему вылетает такой Exception? `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дословно ошибка расшифровывается/переводится так:

`Ожидалось начало объекта, но имеем начало массива, падаю.`

Т.е. в `JSON` у вас массив объектов, а вы пытаетесь парсить весь ответ как один объект.

Вам надо просто указать, что вы ожидаете массив.

```
@GET("data/Shop")
Observable<List<Shop>> listShops();
```